# SwiftUI: ignoreSafeArea causing extra whitespace in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm just learning how to use SwiftUI and seem to be having an issue with the ignoreSafeArea() call on a view.

This is my original View:

[image]

But when I add ignoreSafeArea to the View it causes strange whitespace errors:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using for the main view.

```
var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            Image("Banner")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(height: self.show ? 120 : 70, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                .blur(radius: self.show ? 0 : 2)
                .clipped()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(user.name)
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(user.screenName)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                UserImage(user: user, show: self.$show)
            }
            .padding()
                        
            if self.show {
                Divider()

                HStack {
                        Text(user.userDetailsDescription)
                            .font(.subheadline.weight(.light))
                        Spacer()
                }.padding(.leading)
            }
    }        
}
```

Comment: @TusharSharma On the Image? I've removed it and still get the same behaviour, really confusing. Not sure what else is wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the modifier to the `VStack` instead, so it doesn't just affect `Image("Banner")`.

Change this:

```
VStack {
    Image("Banner")
        /* ... */
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    
    /* ... */
}
```

To this:

```
VStack {
    Image("Banner")
        /* ... */
    
    /* ... */
}
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
```

| Incorrect code | Correct code |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Incorrect] | [image: Correct] |

Comment: I thought I had tried this, but turns out I'd left the list outside the VStack which caused issues! Thanks!

Comment: @aheze yeah, I think it should be okay though, since I plan to have the image across the top the whole time?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could replace the `Image` with a placeholder space (`Color.clear`). Then, put the `Image` inside `.background()`. This way, the image's frame won't affect any other spacing.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let show = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            /// placeholder
            Color.clear
                .frame(height: self.show ? 120 : 70)
                .background(
                    Image("Banner")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(alignment: .bottomLeading)
                        .blur(radius: self.show ? 0 : 2)
                        .ignoresSafeArea() /// ignoresSafeArea inside `.background`
                )
            
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("User name")
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text("User screen name")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: -50)
            }
            .padding()
            
            
            if self.show {
                Divider()
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Description")
                        .font(.subheadline.weight(.light))
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.leading)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Image flows under status bar]